# setTimeout for readonly for text input doesn't work if spammed by user

Tags: javascript, php

I have code that makes it so that if an user enters an input, it'll keep them from entering more input for 3 seconds. This one works, but if you spam the input box, like you enter 1 input per 100 milliseconds or so, it'll override it, make the readOnly false all the time if you keep spamming it at that rate.

```
echo "<input type = 'text' autofocus = 'autofocus' id = 'text' onKeyDown=\"if(event.keyCode==13) ajaxPass('text')
\">";

function ajaxPass(getValueFrom) {

document.getElementById(getValueFrom).readOnly = true;
setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById(getValueFrom).readOnly = false; }, 3000);

}
```

Comment: Sorry but... Why would you wnat to do this to your users?

Comment: @JulioSoares Because a lot of users spams for no reasons, and it's eating a lot of data. For example, a lot of people just enter "asdfasdf" for like 100 times in under 1 minute for no reasons.

Comment: And if people started using spambot to enter 1 message per milliseconds that will kill my website.

Comment: So then you punish the very few that are honestly trying to use your thing?????
why not to use recaptcha or jquery/php validation or something?

Comment: @JulioSoares It's not punishment...It takes around 3 seconds or more to read the outputs anyway...

Comment: check this out... https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html
Trust me. You are not alone and there are much better ways. 3 seconds  is a lot of time... I would give up your site in the second field

Comment: @JulioSoares That will only annoy the real people, and it'll only work against robots. Real people can still spam.

Comment: It is your site... good luck... again robots can be thought to wait while people are not htat patient